# How have I draw picture in printDokument _Printpage in datagridview?

Tags: .net

I know draw the strings DataGrid, but I can not draw the pictures.
Please advise me,  how I should draw image from DataGridView.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thJaI.png)

I used : e.graphics.DrawImage (last line)

```
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Columns[9].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(450, 55));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[9].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(520, 55));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Columns[10].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(450, 75));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[10].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(520, 75));

            // vykreslenie čiar

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen (Brushes.Black, 3), 75 ,190,740,190);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3), 75, 45, 740, 45);

            //vykreslenie Qrcodu
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(dataGridView_nahlad.Rows[0].Cells[12]    , 620, 55, 120, 120);
```

Comment: You just stopped typing too soon.  You have to use the cell's Value property.  And cast it to (Image).

Comment: @HansPassant How do I assign a value?